# unity jumping collisions - how enemy is damaged

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a platformer in Unity using unityscript.

I have a Player parent object with a character controller and various child objects.  I have a similar enemy with a box collider.  I'm struggling to differentiate between the collision happening when the player walks into the enemy and when the the player jumps and collides with it from above.

I've tried tagging the child objects but they don't have colliders. If I add colliders to the child objects, it messes up my character movement. I've also tried to test the position of the player:

```
if(col.transform.position.y >= transform.position.y){ killThyself(); }
```

But this doesn't work either - should I add the height of the enemy? If so how do I do that?

Any suggestions happily received.

Comment: I suggest you to add some code to the question, otherways to get this work depends on how tall enemies you have ; ).

Comment: Assuming you're using OnCollisionEnter, you could use the `normal` variable within each `ContactPoint` to see if it's pointing upward (and therefore you're hitting the top of the collision box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm, I would use a boolean variable. Make it true when you press the jump button, and false once the jump has finished (when the player touches the floor). Declare the boolean as a **public** variable.
After that, in the OnCollision method, check the variable value. 
I recommend you to read this to understand how to do that:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

Well, in your case I would assign the "otherScript" (the player script) doing this in the enemy control script:

```
var player : GameObject;
var playerScript: PlayerScript; 
//I'm assuming "PlayerScript" is the name of the control script of your player, 
//where you defined the "jump" variable.

    function Start()
    {

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    //You also can use GameObject.Find("PlayerName")
    playerScript = player.GetComponent(PlayerScript);
    //Get the script from the player

    }

    function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision)
    {

    if (playerScript.jump == true)
    {
       killThyself();
    }

    }
```

I'm finding the player on the function Start, to find it only ONCE, in the level load. Now, I assign the player script into a variable, so, when the player hit the enemy, this enemy will check if the player is jumping using his script. Remember to declare this variable as a public variable or this won't work.
Please comment if you have any problem using this method =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a second collider at the upper part of the enemy let's called it *headCollider*. Set `isTrigger = true` and maybe use a special physics material. If this *headCollider* is the first one to get triggered you know that the player chararacter is jumping on the enemy or is falling on it from above.

In `OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)` you can prepare some status variables (and maybe a timer for resetting the status). Also the current jump status like in V_Programmer's answer suggested should be useful for evaluation.

As Unity does not allow you to attach 2 colliders of the same kind, you have to use box and sphere or create an empty child and use that one.